# How do I define a full set of orthogonal basis functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I'm doing an undergraduate-level course in media computing. I have some background in linear algebra but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

I'm given a signal = $3 + 2sin(6\pi t) + 7cos(12\pi t) + 5sin(30 \pi t)$ and I am tasked to define a full set of orthogonal basis functions that can space the occupied by sinusoidal signals of $f$ Hz, where $f$ is an integer ranging from 0 to $N$.

I am then tasked to determine what is $N$ so that this set of basis functions defines a space that the aforementioned signal lives in.

How do I go about starting it? What should I be thinking of?

Edit: I am able to solve question 1. I think I have a pretty good idea of what I am looking for with regards to Q2. However, I have no idea as to how to approach it.

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQDRZ.png)

Comment: Your question is a jumbled up confusing mix up of the two questions in your link. Might be better to ask about question 1 first then ask separately about question 2. You should try and show your own thoughts and a bit of what you have done so that people know where to start when answering you.

Comment: @Paul I'm sorry about it and thank you very much for pointing it out. Frankly, I am quite lost on the topic. Pardon me if I mess it up somewhere but IIRC, I am supposed to find the fundamental frequency of this signal and hence the fundamental period, T. Then I am supposed to probe the signal with sine and cosine waves of different frequencies to see if any of it yields a result of T/2. I'm thinking that sines and cosines of frequencies that yield a result of T/2 should form the set of orthogonal basis functions. Can you point out where did i go wrong?

Comment: The fundamental frequency is the greatest common denominator of the 3 frequencies in $sig_1$ (the biggest number that divides into all three). What is that? Second part of Q1 is language dependent (Matlab?) and should be in your notes.

Comment: @Paul Yup, the fundamental frequency is 6 Hz. I've solved Q1 without any issues actually. Q2 seems out of this world for me.

Oh, and yes, we're using Matlab! I'm really new to it so I'm stumbling.. hahaha

Comment: The angular frequency (which is what is usually called the fundamental frequency) is $6\pi$. What is usually called the frequency (in Hz) is then this number divided by $2\pi$, which is 3 Hz. The basis you need in Q2 is a collection of sines and cosines, together with the constant 1.

Comment: @Paul, I'm thinking that N is 15, so I'll have 15 sines and 15 cosines in my set. What do you think?